# Get image shape edges with Image Magick

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am new to ImageMagick and Imagick library in php, and I want to know how can I make everything transparent but leave only the edges of the shape in a png image.

For example I have this picture: [image]

And I want to keep only a thin line formed by the edges of the eagle, and fill the inside of the eagle with transparent color.

Or as an alternative how can I change the black eagle color into a brown rgba color with opacity 0.4 using Image Magick library with php and GD library?

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1**

If you want the outline of the eagle black and everything else transparent, you can use this:

```
convert eagle.png -channel RGBA -separate -delete 0-2 -edge 1 -threshold 1 -transparent black +channel -negate result.png
```

[image]

That separates the image into RGBA channels and discards all except the alpha channel. It then finds the edges of the alpha channel (which show up as white on black) and then makes black pixels transparent and inverts the white ones to black.

My PHP implementation is as follows:

```
<?php
// convert eagle.png -channel RGBA -separate -delete 0-2 -edge 1 -threshold 1 -transparent black +channel -negate result.png
   $image=new Imagick('eagle.png');
   $image->separateimagechannel(Imagick::CHANNEL_OPACITY);
   $image->edgeImage(1);
   $image->thresholdImage(1);
   $image->transparentPaintImage("black",0.0,10,false);
   $image->negateImage(false);
   $image->writeimage('result.png');
?>
```

**Option 2**

If you want to make the black body of the eagle into 40% opaque dark brown, you can do this:

```
convert eagle.png -channel RGBA -fill "rgba(101,67,33,0.4)" -fuzz 10% -opaque black result.png
```

[image]

My PHP implementation is as follows:

```
<?php
// convert eagle.png -channel RGBA -fill "rgba(101,67,33,0.5)" -fuzz 10% -opaque black answer2.png
   $image=new Imagick('eagle.png');
   $image->opaquePaintImage("black","rgba(101,67,33,0.4)",10,false,imagick::CHANNEL_ALL);
   $image->writeimage('result2.png');
?>
```

Comment: +1 for thoroughness. Just for clarification in the last php script, does that leave a black edge around the object in the given image, as it actually appears to do in the image above? Asking for a friend 0_0 ... From what it looks like in the code, it seems to be replacing black with the rgba value for the light brown and a = 0.4... I am uncertain about the `10, false`, and it seems like `imagick::CHANNEL_ALL` is used to obtain all the channels needed as opposed to something like CMYK...

Comment: As per usual, the docs offer a lot of help https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.opaquepaintimage.php

Answer (score 0):

Something like this to detect edges:

```
convert eagle.png --edge 3 eagle-edges.png
```

Within PHP you can use `bool Imagick::edgeImage(float $radius)`.

Comment: This didn't do anything for me, the image was the same after converting it. I made some break through though and achived what I was looking for, but if you have a better solution I am open to it, as I am not 100% satisfied on how it looks. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the result with these commands though I haven't tested yet on other images, only on the one with the eagle.

```
exec('convert eagle.png -charcoal 1 neweagle.png');
exec('convert neweagle.png -transparent white neweagle.png');
```

I am open to other better solutions!!

Also would be great if some knows how to do these commands from the php library without the exec.

Comment: It would help if you clicked `edit` under your question and showed exactly what you want - as you seem to be unclear on whether you want just the outline (in black presumably?), or the outline plus the eagle in semitransparent brown, or a charcoal drawing...